# C static inline function redefinition rules

Tags: c, function, static, shadow, undefined-behavior

Suppose in `bar.h` there *might* exist:

```
static inline int fun () { return 2; }
```

And to ensure that `fun` is always defined `foo.h` contains the following:

```
static inline int fun () { return 3; }
```

Does the following elicit undefined behavior when `bar.h` contains the definition?

```
#include "foo.h" /* ensure there is always a definition */
#include "bar.h" /* use the bar definition if it exists */

int main () {
   /* ... */
   int x = fun ();
   /* ... */
```

With gcc (4.0.1) (old, but it's what I have currently) the behavior is as expected - the foo version is used when the bar version is missing and the bar version is used when it exists.

Comment: I ought to point out that `void func()` and `void func(void)` are subtly different in C.

Comment: @Chris Are you suggesting that I can avoid the undefined behavior by adding an explicit `void` to the signature to only one of the two definitions?

Comment: No, C doesn't allow overloading. It just looks like you intend `int fun(void)` which is more accurate than `int fun()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not allowed.  Those definitions of `fun()` declare `fun()` to have internal linkage (due to the `static`), and §6.9 in the C standard says:

> There shall be no more than one
>   external definition for each
>   identifier declared with internal
>   linkage in a translation unit.

Violation of a "shall" clause is undefined behaviour, which means that the semantics of your program are completely undefined, and the compiler doesn't have to issue an error message.

Comment: That reference was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to do that, and your compiler shouldn't let you.

You can have multiple definitions of a non-static inlined function only if all the definitions are identical (but never more than one definition per TU). This will necessarily happen for inlined functions defined in header files.

For static linkage each TU can have a different definition, but you can still only have one definition per TU.

*(Sorry for the multiple edits.)*

Comment: I've tried `gcc -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` without complaint. Only with `-ansi` is there a problem. But then, at that point, there is also a problem with the `inline`.

Comment: @ezpz: What exactly are you compiling? I get "error: redefinition" with your example. Do you have include guards in the header files?

Comment: No include guards. Each header only has the single definition in it and the source is mostly as listed in my question. I guess I will have to try a more recent compiler version when I get to one.

Comment: @ezpz - FYI, the `ansi` problem is because `inline` is a C99 addition, and the `ansi` flag forces C89 standards.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve the same effect, you can use a harmless macro:

```
// foo.h - include guards omitted because of iPhone
#ifndef VALUE
# define VALUE 2
#endif

static inline int fun() { return VALUE; }

// bar.h
#define VALUE 3
#include "foo.h"
```

Include order flips, but it's less scary than the full macro version (which isn't scary at all IMHO but I don't know your/your workplace's relationships with macros.)